# How to compare matrices in GNU Octave

Tags: matrix, octave, gnu, comparison-operators

I would like to compare A*A(-1) with identity matrix. They are equal, but Octave says they are not and I have no idea why...
https://ibb.co/mHBGKwb

Comment: I think the duplicate linked is the reason why you are having this problem. You can not compare floating points numbers with `==`.

Comment: However, please, do not ever share code as an image. Its completely useless. Its text, share it as text.